# DATE_ADD MySQL function selection with date in condition

Tags: mysql, sql, date

When I try this query:

```sql
SELECT DATE_ADD(upg_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS 'upgrade_date'
WHERE id=12345
```

it returns me the record with the correct value, but when I add a condition like this:

```sql
SELECT DATE_ADD(upg_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS 'upgrade_date'
WHERE id=12345
AND 'upgrade_date' < NOW()
```

it returns an empty result set. But value of the `upgrade_date` is lower than current date.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot use the `alias`** in the `where` clause. It should be the original column name.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(upg_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS upgrade_date
WHERE id=12345 AND 
      upg_date < NOW()
```

From the **[MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)**:

**It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quotes on the WHERE clause and alias

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(upg_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS upgrade_date
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
WHERE id=12345
AND upgrade_date < NOW()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the quotes turn that upgrade_date into a string value, not the field alias you created earlier.

Comment: But in this case I got an error #1054 - Unknown column 'upgrade_date' in 'where clause'

Comment: Where exactly does `bonus_date` show up in your query? it's not in your sample.

Comment: you **can't use alias in where clause**. but you can use on `having.